# Feature installation from the command line - missing dependencies

Tags: eclipse, command-line, installation

I want to automatically setup a test environment starting from a fresh eclipse install. I would like to install some features from the command line. However, although installing the feature from the IDE works, it does not with the following Command line script (line breaks added for convenience):

```
H:/eclipse/eclipsec.exe 
-application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 
-repository http://download.eclipse.org/recommenders/updates/head/ 
-installIU org.eclipse.recommenders.rcp.feature.feature.group 
-destination H:/eclipse/ 
-profile SDKProfile 
-verifyOnly
```

This gives me the error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
 Software being installed: Code Recommenders Developer Tools (Milestone) 2.0.1.v
20131111-0948 (org.eclipse.recommenders.rcp.feature.feature.group 2.0.1.v2013111
1-0948)
 Missing requirement: async-http-client 1.6.5.20130531-2315 (com.ning.async-http
-client 1.6.5.20130531-2315) requires 'package javax.crypto 0.0.0' but it could
not be found
 Cannot satisfy dependency:
  From: Embedded Maven Runtime Bundle 1.4.0.20130531-2315 (org.eclipse.m2e.maven
.runtime 1.4.0.20130531-2315)
  To: bundle com.ning.async-http-client [1.6.5,1.6.6)
 Cannot satisfy dependency:
  From: Code Recommenders: Models Runtime 2.0.1.v20131110-1920 (org.eclipse.reco
mmenders.models 2.0.1.v20131110-1920)
  To: package org.sonatype.aether 0.0.0
 Cannot satisfy dependency:
  From: Code Recommenders Developer Tools (Milestone) 2.0.1.v20131111-0948 (org.
eclipse.recommenders.rcp.feature.feature.group 2.0.1.v20131111-0948)
  To: org.eclipse.recommenders.models [2.0.1.v20131110-1920]
Application failed, log file location: H:\eclipse\configuration\1384270274500.log
```

What's happening here (differently from the IDE), and how can i make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have the `contact all update sites during install to find required software` option set in the Install New Software dialog in the IDE.

To duplicate the IDE behavior you need to specify all the necessary repositories as a comma separated listed as the argument to `-repository`.